# Select dropdown option to display a predefined price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Hi everyone I hope you can help me today.

I am creating a pricing page for my business and I need a select dropdown to display a list of bedrooms, e.g. 1 Bedroom, 2 Bedrooms, 3 Bedrooms etc.

When an option has been selected, a div below will display a price. E.g. if I select 4 bedrooms from the dropdown, the text below the dropdown field will display £100. If I select 3 bedrooms, the price below will display £80. It needs to be separate from the dropdown field.

The concept is simple but I am asking for help in terms of its functionality. I have searched for jQuery sliders that can do this for me but have not found anything suitable that is user friendly for what I require it to display.

All help, as always, is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is less *help* ing you and more doing the whole thing for you, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/m8K5Y/1/) you go

Comment: please show us some example which you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy achieve this by using `onchange` event of `dropdown`. Save the value of price in value attribute of options.
like :

HTML

```
<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option>Choose beds</option>
  <option value="150">1 bed</option>
  <option value="200">2 beds</option>
  <option value="300">3 beds</option>
  <option value="400">4 beds</option>
</select>

<div id="divprice"></div>
```

then on `"onchange"` event put the value of selected item in `"divprice"` element.

Javascript will looks like

```
function changeddl($this){
   $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("price: $ " + $this.value):"");
};
```

check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmG2/2/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmG2/)

This's a possible solution:

### html code

```
<select id="bedrooms">
  <option>Choose beds</option>
  <option value="150">1 bed</option>
  <option value="200">2 beds</option>
  <option value="300">3 beds</option>
  <option value="400">4 beds</option>
</select>

<div id="price"></div>
```

### Javascript code

```
$("#bedrooms").change(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
        $("#price").html("price: $ " + $(this).val());
    } else {
        $("#price").empty();
    };
});
```

Comment: ReDEyeS beat me to it, but I'd just like to add the option of using `onchange` events, so you could have something like `<select id="bedrooms" onchange="updatePriceDisplay();">`, and call the JavaScript function like that.